# Authorisation and Chained Method Combined process of Paypal

Tags: asp.net, paypal, authorization

I want to Implement these things in project please give me guidance how to implement

My clients requirement is:-1. Buyer authorizes the work by clicking “Order”.The system will create an authorization code, but doesn’t charge the buyer just yet. 2.The seller now receives a notification to proceed.3. Once the seller goes his profile page which shows his/her pending orders, there will be a button to click
once he/she is finished with the order. That button will alert the buyer that the order is complete. In the next 3 days, there are 3 possible scenarios:a) Buyer confirms that the order is complete and satisfactory. At this point,Paypal will send money to the seller and to Admin of website(commission).
b) Buyer does not approve and will discuss with the seller ways to fix the order. Buyer and seller have 3 days
to discuss and resolve. Buyer now has an option to request to cancel the order.
c) The buyer takes no action and once the 3 days are up, the seller will be paid and Admin gets our commission.
If Scenario B happens and the buyer does not click “request to cancel” within those 3 days, then payment
will automatically be made to seller. 6. Once the buyer clicks “request to cancel” the admins will go in and view the communication/messages
between the buyer and seller and determine who gets the final payment from paypal.

Can I implement these things in my project using Paypal. Which method can apply for this process.

Answer (score 0):

This could be implemented by combination of [PayPal's Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) + your own business logic via API calls to PayPal servers.